# Can't access Cordova inside React application

Tags: reactjs, cordova

I am trying to access Cordova from my React application.

After build, everything I am trying to do to access it isn't working - I am trying window.cordova, and have used just cordova by itself.

For example, demo code in one of my components:

```
if(window.cordova) {
    return(
 <div>Cordova is here</div>
    )
}
```

I've tried putting cordova.js in both my index.html in the header as well as the body.

No luck.

How do I get access to Cordova in React?

Comment: You do not need to add cordova.js manually, it is added by Cordova every time you compile... are you running the app in the emulator or real device?

Comment: I figured out what the issue was here - it was totally unrelated to anything Cordova. It was related to a React Redux store - createBrowserHistory. Solution was switch to createHashHistory.